# Is there a way to sanitize or validate a form without modifying each one?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, sanitization

In the project I was assigned to, I found a problem: inputs are not sanitized.
In certain parts, data is sent and received using XHTML; however, in the `type=text` inputs, if you introduce "<" or ">", when it reaches the Backend (Java), it gives an error.

Since there are A LOT of inputs (literally, a lot), restricting those patterns is time consuming. There are also a lot of forms, so it is the same thing (but in a lesser number of incidences). Is there a way to implement a sanitizer-like method without modifying each form or input?

Comment: The backend should almost never error out when `<` or `>` are received, those characters should generally be removed for safety in the serverside validation, if they aren't expected, and clientside validation doesn't really solve that issue.

Comment: You're not supposed to "sanitize" input. You're supposed to *escape output* (to HTML, to database, etc).

Comment: The problem surfaces when, i.e, i try to register the name "<zxz<zx"
When the back en tries to save it, since its received as an xhtml it takes those chars as a tag and it crashes. that is what im trying to limit or exclude in the front end, is that wrong?

Comment: Send all your requests from frontend's after you've escaped them, or escape them before you save in the backend.

Comment: All of you guys are right, thank you so much for explaining it to me, i am doing the html escape on back end since it is easier, Thank you so much for your time!